# HMAC SHA256 decrypt string in C#

Tags: c#, encryption

How can I decrypt HMAC SHA256 encrypted string?

```
private string CreateToken(string message, string secret)
    {
      secret = secret ?? "";
      var encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
      byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(secret);
      byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
      using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
      {
        byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hashmessage);
      }
    }
```

How can I do reverse engineering if I have resultant string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope, this is not reversible, just like all forms of cryptographic hashing.

Comment: You can get more information if you look here
http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34219/is-it-possible-to-get-the-encryption-key-when-you-have-the-plaintext

Answer (score 6):

A hash is a one-way function, by definition it is not reversible. What is it that you are trying to achieve?

If it's for something like password comparison then just hash the password you have and then compare the resulting hashes. Without any further context it's hard what to suggest.

Comment: Not exactly _one-way_ because in some cases you are able to bruteforce expected result.

Comment: If you're using a hash that can be brute-forced then you need to ask why you're using it in the first place. Much like with the depreciation of SHA1.

If you want me to clarify then the intended purpose of a hash is for it to be a one-way function.

Comment: @m.rogalski Perthaps "bruteforce" is not the correct term. It is possible to try suspected values but that is not really "bruteforce".

Answer (score 2):

**HMACSHA256:** It is a hash based Message authentication code.It is used to verify the message integrity on the insecure channel.It is a forward only hash algorithm, it can not be decrypted. It hashes the message based on the shared secret key which is known by both parties(sender and receiver).Sender uses the shared secret and compute the hash value from original data and send both the original data and hash value and then receiver re-computes the hash value from the original data. If both hash value matches it means no tempered in original data, if not matched it means tempered in original data for this scenario validation is failed.

Comment: Clearly explained but need some spell/grammatical checking.